# I need to replace C comments with a blank space or new line using sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

The input file is like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // this is a function
    float alpha = 0;
    // test
    /* */
    int y = 11; // comment
    y = y + 15;
    //
    char z = 'n';
    /* end of file 
    c */
}
```

And the desired output should look like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    *
    float alpha = 0;*
    *
    *
    int y = 11; *
    y = y + 15;*
    *
    char z = 'n';*
*
*
}
```

Here the * represents EOL.

I have tried this but it simply deletes the spaces and new lines too.

```
sed '/^[ \t]*\/\//d;/\/*\*\//d;/^[ \t]*\/\*/d' $[input file]
```

Comment: IMHO, Its always advisable by experts to use tools for editing code which understand the code's formatting styles, may be some tool which can understand C formatting `sed` may do it but you may fall into issues in case your actual file is different from shown samples.

Comment: I need to make a regular expression so that it can remove comments in any C file

Comment: Make sure `const char *s = "foo // bar";` doesn't break it.

Comment: Isn't this an exercise in K&R? Except without regular expressions; most solutions end up creating a state machine iirc.

Comment: Any general solution using `sed` or a similar regex-based solution is going to run foul of a variety of circumstances where the regex sees a comment and the compiler doesn't.  For example, `printf("/* this is not a comment */");`.  Variations include `'/*'`, `'*/'`, `'//'` — multi-character character constants are permitted, though the value is implementation-defined.  That's before you start to deal with backslash-newline nasties.  You can, though very few people do, split comment start or end markers across lines with backslash-newline. Also, `//` comments are continued by backslash-newline.

Comment: You also have to be careful about `// /* not a multi-line comment` and related constructions (`/* // not a single line comment…` etc.).

Comment: Roughly speaking, the goal of creating "a regular expression so that it can remove comments in any C file" is not reasonable. Tools can be written (I've written one); such tools are not trivial to write. C++ is harder than C — constructs such as `0b0101'1010'1111'0000` (a binary literal in C++) can easily confuse a naïve regex-based parser because it looks for all the world as if there is the start of a multi-character literal with the third single quote. Fixing that naïveté is not a trivial exercise. Raw character string literals are another complication in C++, mercifully absent from C.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -z 's#//[^\n]*##g
        s#/\*#\x00#g
        s#\*/#\x01#g
        s/\x00[^\n\x00\x01]*\x01//g;tb
        :b;s/\x00[^\x01\n]*\n/\n\x00/;tb;s/\x00[^\n]*\x01//;tb' file
```

The solution comes in 3 parts:

1. Single line comments are removed
2. Multi line comments on a single line are removed.
3. Multi line comments on multiple lines are removed but the newlines of such lines are retained.

The solution uses the `-z` option which may cause problems if the file contains `null` characters.

N.B. This solution is only partial as many corner cases may break it e.g. literal comments as part of a variable value.

Comment: See my [notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67138348/i-need-to-replace-c-comments-with-a-blank-space-or-new-line-using-sed#comment118687761_67138348) about how your script can be fooled.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler note the second word of all my solutions!

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\/\/.*//;s/\/\*.*//;s/.*\*\///' file
```

The command works as following:- the first part searches for the string "//" and then eliminates the {string} followed by it on the same line. The second part searches for the string "/*" and then eliminates the {string} followed by it on the same line. the third part searches for the string "*/" and then eliminates the {string} followed by it on the same line. The failure for the given solution would be when the multi-line comment exceeds more than 2 lines

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: The command works as following:-
the first part searches for the string "//" and then eliminates the {string} followed by it on the same line.
The second part searches for the string "/*" and then eliminates the {string} followed by it on the same line.
the third part searches for the string "*/" and then eliminates the {string} followed by it on the same line.
The failure for the given solution would be when the multi-line comment exceeds more than 2 lines.

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer by editing it

Comment: What about string like: `http://example.com`? Your regex will keep `http:` and delete the rest. Not sure that's the wanted behaviour!